# Capturing 'find' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle

Tags: objective-c-blocks

I have this chunk of code:

```
- (void) resotreEntitySelectionForHistoryObject:(CoreDataHistoryObject *)historyObject {
    OutlineViewNode *(^__block find)(OutlineViewNode *, NSString *) = ^OutlineViewNode *(OutlineViewNode *node, NSString *title) {
        if ([node.title isEqualToString:title]) {
            return node;
        }

        for (OutlineViewNode *child in node.childs) {
            OutlineViewNode *result = find(child, title);
            if (result) {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return nil;
    };

    OutlineViewNode *node = find(self.rootNode, historyObject.name);

    if (node) {
        [self.dataSourceList selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[self.dataSourceList rowForItem:node]] byExtendingSelection:NO];
    }
}
```

And I get this compiler warning:

- CoreDataUtility/CoreDataUtil/MFLMainWindowController.m:230:39: Capturing 'find' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle *

It is on this line "OutlineViewNode *result = find(child, title);"

I know a solution to just create a method instead of a block. But now this has got me thinking about how can you return a value from a block.

For your reference you can view full source code here:

https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility/blob/master/CoreDataUtil/MFLMainWindowController.m#L224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block captures the variable `find`, which is set to point to the block. So the block has a strong reference to itself, so it has a retain cycle.

To do it right, you need two variables that point to the block, one weak and one strong. The block will capture the weak one to not have a strong reference to itself. The strong one is necessary to maintain a reference to the block at all.

```
OutlineViewNode *(^find)(OutlineViewNode *, NSString *);
__block OutlineViewNode *(^ __weak findWeak)(OutlineViewNode *, NSString *);
findWeak = find = ^OutlineViewNode *(OutlineViewNode *node, NSString *title) {
    if ([node.title isEqualToString:title]) {
        return node;
    }

    for (OutlineViewNode *child in node.childs) {
        OutlineViewNode *result = findWeak(child, title);
        if (result) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return nil;
};

OutlineViewNode *node = find(self.rootNode, historyObject.name);
```

Comment: I tried the code above but it generates compile errors. If I add the ';' characters It get back to the same warning.

Comment: @Yepher: edited. it seems it's picky about the order of assignments (even though it shouldn't)